# Show that $L\geq2\pi|f'(0)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on and inside the unit circle $\partial\mathbb{D}$. Let $L$ be the length of the curve $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$. Show that $L\geq2\pi|f'(0)|$.

I have tried different approaches from Schwarz Lemma, and maximum modulus principle, but got nowhere. Any guidance is appreciated.

Edit:
I think I may have found it (please confirm):
By maximum modulus principle, $f$ attains it's max value on $\partial\mathbb{D}$. By Cauchy Estimates: 
$$\begin{align*}
|f'(0)|\leq|\sup f|
\end{align*}$$
Note that since $L=2\pi |\sup f|$, we conclude that 
$$\begin{align*}|f'(0)|&\leq \frac{L}{2\pi}\\
2\pi|f'(0)|&\leq L
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Why does $L=2\pi\lvert\sup f\rvert$?  What does it mean to take sup of (strictly) complex numbers?

Comment: @user10354138 Circumference of a circle is defined by $2\pi\cdot r$. Here, radius is $f(z)$ where $|z|=1$. Since, by maximum modulus principle, that's where $f$ attains its maximum, i.e. $|\sup f|$. I may be totally wrong.

Comment: @YaG But $f(\partial \mathbb{D})$ need not be a circle

Comment: @angryavian Hmm I can see that. I think I just took that for granted. May be we can find a close circle completely contained in $L$?

Comment: @YaG Also, I think user10354138 is trying to get you notice that you probably meant $\sup |f|$ rather than $|\sup f|$.

Comment: That is one aspect of it.  The other part is indeed $f(\partial\mathbb{D})$ need not be a circle and $f$ need not be univalent, so it doesn't make sense to multiply by $2\pi$ and say it is $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From definition of length of a curve and mean value property:
$$L = \int_0^{2\pi} |(f(e^{it}))'| dt = \int_0^{2\pi} |f'(e^{it})|dt \geq\left|\int_0^{2\pi}f'(e^{it})dt \right| = 2\pi |f'(0)| $$